# Int pointers having weird behavior in C

Tags: c, pointers, int, dereference

```
void main(){
  int digits[21]; //this was initialized so that every element is 0 by looping over every element and setting it to 0
  char input[20];
  scanf("%s", input);
  parseDigits(digits, input);
}

void parseDigits(int* digits, char *string){
  char *end = string + strlen(string) -1;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(string) - 1; i++, end--){
    int *digit = digits + i;
    printf("%d", *digit);
    *digit += charToDigit(*end);
    if (*digit >= 10){ //carry one
      *digit -= 10;
      digit++;
      *digit += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Prints an excessively large integer, instead of 0, which is the expected output. I don't understand since

```
digits + i
```

should still be within the range of the array.

Comment: How did you initialize this array `int digits[21];` ?

Comment: "this was initialized so that every element is 0" Where was that done? Not in the code you're showing.

Comment: Mike, comments do not magically induce the desired behaviour to occur. You have to actually write the code that the comment alludes to.

Comment: what is `charToDigit` ??

Comment: You write _//this was initialized so that every element is 0_. That's simply wrong. Ths `digits` array isn't inizialized at all so it contains random values.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this piece of code?

Comment: Still having issues with this post?

Answer (score 1):

There can be other issues, but from first glance you have not initialized your array properly, which should have been done like:

`int digits[21] = { 0 };`

Comment: I looped through every element by setting each element to zero, but it turns out I did it wrong. Apparently the iterator was not set to 0.

Thank you for showing me a new way to initialize values in an array.

Comment: @MikeTravis This isn't a "new" way, this is _the_ way to initialize arrays, there is just one. Everything else is run-time assignment.